# Gerrit Code Review - How to download a file with wget using http password?

Tags: wget, gerrit

I'd like to donwload a single file from a gerrit server which a no read access for anonymous users. 
Therefore I set the **http password** for the user and tried something like: 
`wget --user=user --password=passwd "http://example.com:8443/gitweb/?p=...;a=blob_plain;f=...;hb=refs/heads/master"`

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Unknown authentication scheme.
```

Is this possible at all using the http password generated in the user settings of gerrit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it possible to use the HTTP password generated in the user setting. Have a look at the Authentication documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#authentication).

However, Gerrit Code Review doesn't allow you to download a single file (unless you have a particular plugin installed to do so). Are you sure downloading a single file is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

the following works for me:

```
http://your gerrit:8080/gitweb?p=your repository.git;a=blob_plain;f=path/to/file -O file
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).